# How to call certain string in MYSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my input data:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3WrM.png

If user input data like:

```
> CALL Hobbies_Input('football')
> 
> CALL Hobbies_Input('Badminton')
> 
> CALL Hobbies_Input('Cricket')
```

They should get their respective outputs.

I tried to do this, Here's my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER &&
CREATE PROCEDURE Hobbies_Input (IN var1 VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN  
    SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Hobbies, var1);
END &&
DELIMITER;
```

It's working for my first case[CALL Hobbies_Input('football')]
But its showing zero rows for my second and third case, how can i rectify this?

Comment: Find _in Set can't find data in a delimited column so read up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and normalize your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this work?

```
DELIMITER &&
CREATE PROCEDURE Hobbies_Input (IN var1 VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN  
    SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE FIND_IN_SET(REPLACE(Hobbies, ';', ','), var1);
END &&
DELIMITER;
```